# Cost/benefit of fixing an ESD issue?

Tags: esd

As electrical engineers, we often go to great lengths to make our electronics designs robust to ESD strikes.  However, I was wondering if this is sometimes overkill.  Suppose you are making something like a kickstarter project, and you know that your system may experience failures from ESD, but you are willing to offer refunds to any customers that experience this.  How common are ESD failures, really?  Would something like 1% of users typically experience an ESD issue during the product life?  0.1%?

Imagine if your product is a consumer product (not medical or government) consisting of a board in a plastic enclosure, with some I/O ports and maybe buttons and LEDs.  Perhaps something like this picture:  [https://www.amazon.com/SunFounder-Enclosure-Transparent-Computer-Compatible/dp/B00HNMOH0C/ref=sr_1_2?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1466385325&sr=1-2&keywords=arduino+with+enclosure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HNMOH0C)

Comment: That completely depends on the industry and application.

Comment: I understand, I'm just looking for a rough order of magnitude, for something like https://www.amazon.com/SunFounder-Enclosure-Transparent-Computer-Compatible/dp/B00HNMOH0C/ref=sr_1_2?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1466385325&sr=1-2&keywords=arduino+with+enclosure

Comment: That's an acrylic case, not an electronic product.

Comment: What I mean is, imagine if you were building and selling the combination of the Arduino board + the case.  
I.E., your product is a consumer product (not medical or government) consisting of a board in an enclosure with some I/O ports and maybe buttons and LEDs.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to predict something like that. Furthermore, there's no way to predict how even a single failure in the hands of a reviewer will affect the public *perception* of the quality of your product. If you know you have an issue, you'll generally be much better off fixing it than trying to clean up after it.

Comment: I understand, I'm just looking for a rough order of magnitude, for something like https://www.amazon.com/SunFounder-Enclosure-Transparent-Computer-Compatible/dp/B00HNMOH0C/ref=sr_1_2?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1466385325&sr=1-2&keywords=arduino+with+enclosure

Answer (score -2):

There are government agency rules and regulations that dictate things about what a product being sold must comply with. There are rules like this for the USA and similar rules for the EU area. One part of these rules and regulations are prescribed tests that dictate that products must be tested against certain levels of simulated ESD events. The voltage levels will vary according to product type and industry (i.e. product application area). In some cases the product must just remain safe but in many cases the product must remain operational through such tests. Some readings of the regulations even require that the product be self recovering in the case that the ESD event temporarily upsets part of the internal circuitry.

So there is no legal way to get out of this. And you do not want to face the fines that would be accessed against you if you are found to be selling a non-compliant product in a regulated category.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter (yet) but if I'm not mistaken, there's a lot of exceptions when it comes to all these regulations, involving how many you sell, the intended purpose and market, etc. Scaring a lot of hobbyists with laws that do not apply would not be constructive, but I can not answer for a market I'm not familiar with. Are you _sure_ these tests apply for small runs of hobbyist development platforms?

Comment: What I have anecdotally heard with regard to consumer products in the USA is that if you plan to sell in retail stores, the retail store owners will prefer you to meet ESD standards, so that they can have some confidence they won't have to deal with a lot of returns.

Comment: Do not go by what you have heard via idle chit chat. Go by the law! You can choose to self certify but in that case make sure you have the capitalization in place to cover any challenge that may be made to that self certification. In other words make damn sure you know the legal aspects and requirements regarding the product that you intend to sell.